# Change Selected Index of Tab Bar Application from Modal View Controller ios7

Tags: ios7, uitabbarcontroller

I am presenting a modal view controller off of one my tabs in ios7. Depending on the user's action, I want to change the selected index of the tab bar controller.
I have tried 
      [(UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController setSelectedIndex:0];

This does not change the selectedindex of the underlying tab bar. Please let me knwo if there is another way to do this

Comment: This should work finally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just do

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.presentingViewController;
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

Comment: could I preserve the model view controller, so I can change back at some time